# Use jquery to reopen last active accordion panel after page reload

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a page with accordions. When you open one of the panels it lists various links to other pages on the site. If you click on one of these links the target page will open in a lightbox and the user will make changes and submit a form within this lightbox. Once the change has been submitted the lightbox will automatically close and the parent page will reload. The reload is necessary as it displays a summary of the values that were updated in the lightbox so without reloading the summary it would just show the old values. The problem is that I need the previously active panel to go back to that state. Is there an easy way to do this? Alternatively is it possible to reload only the div containing the updated data so that the whole page is not reloaded? My code is as below (panel two is active):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // Refreshes the page. Called from the page shown in the lightbox
      function refreshPage() {      
      // reload
      window.location.reload();
      }
   </script>

<div id="container">   
   <div id="panelOne">
      <div class="Accordion ui-accordion" role="tablist">
         <h3 class="AccordionHeader ui-state-default" role="tab" aria-expanded="false"     aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
            <div><span><a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Panel One</a></span>    </div>
         </h3>
         <div class="AccordionContent" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">
            <div id="Content1">

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
   <div id="panelTwo">
      <div class="Accordion ui-accordion" role="tablist">
         <h3 class="AccordionHeader ui-state-active" role="tab" aria-expanded="true"     aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
            <div><span><a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Panel Two</a></span>    </div>
         </h3>
         <div class="AccordionContent ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel"         style="display: block;">
            <div id="Content2">

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
   <div id="panelThree">
      <div class="Accordion ui-accordion" role="tablist">
         <h3 class="AccordionHeader ui-state-default" role="tab" aria-expanded="true"     aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
            <div><span><a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Panel Three</a>        </span></div>
         </h3>
         <div class="AccordionContent" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">
            <div id="Content3">

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .load() will allow you to fetch just a portion of a document. See: http://api.jquery.com/load/

For example:

```
$('#summary').load('somepage.html #summary > *');
```

Loads the content of the element #summary from the page somepage.html into the current element  #summary

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I've updated my JS code however when I submit I now get an error - "Uncaught Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: An element with id 'aspnetForm' could not be found. Parameter name: elementOrElementId". Changing the JS src to use a closing tag (which I read might help) did not fix this issue. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Is it directly related to the accordion issue or has that been solved and a new bug been found? Sounds like a different issue entirely to me. You should start a new question for it. A .net coder may have some insights.